# Pytorch 'Tensor' object is not callable

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, gradient, sobel

I am trying to apply sobel filter to my network. I am getting this error : "*'Tensor' object is not callable*" 
Here is my code:

```
class SobelFilter(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SobelFilter, self).__init__()

        kernel1=torch.Tensor([[1, 0, -1],[2,0,-2],[1,0,-1]])
        kernela=kernel1.expand((1,1,3,3))

        kernel2=torch.Tensor([[1, 2, 1],[0,0,0],[-1,-2,-1]])
        kernelb=kernel2.expand((1,1,3,3))

        inputs = torch.randn(1,1,64,128)

        self.conv1 = F.conv2d(inputs,kernela,stride=1,padding=1)
        self.conv2 = F.conv2d(inputs,kernelb,stride=1,padding=1)

    def forward(self, x ):

        print(x.shape)
        G_x = self.conv1(x)    %GIVES ERROR AT THIS LINE
        G_y = self.conv2(x)
        out = torch.sqrt(torch.pow(G_x,2)+ torch.pow(G_y,2))

        return out
```

```
class EXP(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, maxdisp):
        super(EXP, self).__init__()
        self.device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
        self.SobelFilter = SobelFilter()

    def forward(self, im):
        % just think "im" to be [1,32,64,128]

        for i in range(im.shape[1]):
            out1= im[:,i,:,:].unsqueeze(1)
            im[:,i,:,:] = self.SobelFilter(out1)
```

what can cause the problem?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue is that you are using `torch.nn.functional` instead of just `torch`. 
The purpose of the functional API is to perform the operations (in this case the conv2d) directly, without creating a class instance and then calling its forward method.
Therefore, the statement `self.conv1 = F.conv2d(inputs,kernela,stride=1,padding=1)` is already doing the convolution between the `input` and `kernela` and what you have in `self.conv1`is the result of such convolution. 
There are two approaches here to fix the problem. Use `torch.Conv2d` inside `__init__`, where `inputs` is the channel of the input and not a tensor with the same shape as your real input.
And the second approach is to stick with the functional API but move it to the `forward()` method. What you want to achieve can be done by changing the forward to:

```py
def forward(self, x ):
  print(x.shape)
  G_x = F.conv2d(x,self.kernela,stride=1,padding=1)
  G_y = F.conv2d(x,self.kernelb,stride=1,padding=1)
  out = torch.sqrt(torch.pow(G_x,2)+ torch.pow(G_y,2))
  return out
```

Note that I made `kernela` and `kernelb` class attributes. Thus you should also change the `__init__()` to

```py
def __init__(self):
  super(SobelFilter, self).__init__()

  kernel1=torch.Tensor([[1, 0, -1],[2,0,-2],[1,0,-1]])
  self.kernela=kernel1.expand((1,1,3,3))

  kernel2=torch.Tensor([[1, 2, 1],[0,0,0],[-1,-2,-1]])
  self.kernelb=kernel2.expand((1,1,3,3))
```

Comment: Thank you! it worked. I also added "self.inputs" instead of just "inputs"

Comment: Code worked but, the output is not what I want. Output looks like mixed random variables. I wanted to apply sobel filter to get the edges ... :(

Comment: I updated the forward, make sure that you add the variable `x` inside `F.conv2d()` call. Let me know if it works now :)

Comment: now it says "RuntimeError: Input type (torch.cuda.FloatTensor) and weight type (torch.FloatTensor) should be the same"

Comment: The error itself seems pretty explanatory. One of the tensors has been moved to the GPU through the `.cuda()` call while the other remains in CPU. Make sure both are in CPU or GPU

Comment: I work with GPU, however "sobelFilter" class was created in CPU (when I push the tensor to CPU, it is working), The question is how can I push the sobelfilter class to GPU ? Btw Thank you  :)

Comment: OK. I have added  `.cuda() ` at the end of  `kernel1=torch.Tensor([[1, 0, -1],[2,0,-2],[1,0,-1]])` then it worked:)

Comment: you could add a method inside the class `def to(self, device, dtype=None):` and inside this method call `self.kernela = self.kernela.to(device, dtype)` (do the same with `kernelb`). Then, after you create the class `SF = SobelFilter(...)` do `SF.to(device, dtype)`, with `device` and `dtype` the device and type of your choice.